# Aggregate Function on Uniqueidentifier (GUID)

Tags: sql, sql-server, guid, aggregate, uniqueidentifier

Let's say I have the following table:

```
category | guid
---------+-----------------------
   A     | 5BC2...
   A     | 6A1C...
   B     | 92A2...
```

Basically, I want to do the following SQL:

```
SELECT category, MIN(guid)
  FROM myTable
 GROUP BY category
```

It doesn't necessarily have to be MIN. I just want to return *one* GUID of each category. I don't care which one. Unfortunately, SQL Server does not allow MIN or MAX on GUIDs.

Of course, I could convert the guid into a varchar, or create some nested TOP 1 SQL, but that seems like an ugly workaround. Is there some elegant solution that I've missed?

Comment: Why are you doing this? Can you just use `SELECT DISTINCT category FROM myTable` instead? Or do you really need an arbitrary GUID for each category?

Comment: @veredesmarald: Yes, I need an arbitrary GUID for each category.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Assuming you're using SQL Server 2005 or later:

```
;with Numbered as (
     select category,guid,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY guid) rn
     from myTable
)
select * from Numbered where rn=1
```

Answer (score 50):

Just cast it as a `BINARY(16)`.

```
SELECT category, MIN(CAST(guid AS BINARY(16)))
FROM myTable
GROUP BY category
```

You can cast it back later if necessary.

```
WITH CategoryValue
AS
(    
    SELECT category, MIN(CAST(guid AS BINARY(16)))
    FROM myTable
    GROUP BY category
)
SELECT category, CAST(guid AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
FROM CategoryValue
```

Comment: you could convert it to a string - `MIN(CAST(guid AS VARCHAR(36)))`

Answer (score 19):

Aggregate functions can be used on Uniqueidentifier columns if SQL Server Version >= 2012

> expression
>
> Is a constant, column name, or function, and any combination of
>   arithmetic, bitwise, and string operators. MIN can be used with
>   numeric, char, varchar, uniqueidentifier, or datetime columns, but not
>   with bit columns. Aggregate functions and subqueries are not
>   permitted.

Comment: +1 - Link to `MIN` in [2008 R2](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179916(v=sql.105).aspx) vs [2012](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179916(v=sql.110).aspx)

Answer (score 4):

```
declare @T table(category char(1), guid uniqueidentifier) 

insert into @T 
select 'a', newid() union all
select 'a', newid() union all
select 'b', newid()

select
  S.category,
  S.guid
from
(  
  select
    T.category,
    T.guid,
    row_number() over(partition by T.category order by (select 1)) as rn
  from @T as T
) as S
where S.rn = 1
```

If you are on SQL Server 2000 you could to this

```
select 
  T1.category,
  (select top 1 T2.guid 
   from @T as T2
   where T1.category = T2.category) as guid
from @T as T1
group by T1.category
```

Answer (score -4):

SELECT top 1 category, guid
  FROM myTable
 GROUP BY category,guid

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but your answer is incorrect: TOP 1 will return only 1 record *after* grouping (i.e., the answer will contain only *either* `A` *or* `B`).