# Guid: How can I get latest inserted record via LINQ to Entites?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6, guid

I'm using below code to fetch latest inserted record:

```
public Request GetLastRequest()
{
    return _request.Find(_request.Max(p => p.Id));
}
```

As you can see `Id` is type of `Guid`:

```
public class Request
{
        public Request()
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        }
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

}
```

After running my code, I'm getting this error:

```
An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code
```

**PS**: above code works if I use `int` for `Id`.

Comment: At which point you are getting Error?

Comment: @Rahul Inside `GetLastRequest()` method. return

Comment: Guids are only meant to be unique, they are not meant to be ordered.  You can not do Max on a Guid in SQL Server, thus it is not supported by EF.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069368/aggregate-function-on-uniqueidentifier-guid

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to timestamp the record or put an auto-incrementing int on the record - GUIDs are generated randomly, so they won't actually represent a "max" GUID after insertion.

If your main intent is to get the record after inserting it, you could generate the GUID in your application layer and insert it into the database, this way you can return the GUID you just inserted in order to query back into the database for your information.

Answer (score 1):

This works with `int` because entity framework can translate the `Max()`-linq-method to the appropriate sql-function. But it fails for `Guid` as they are not supported.

Take a look at this (scroll down to **MAX( expression )**): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399163%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

> A Collection (T) where T is one of the following types: Byte, Int16, Int32, Int64, Byte, Single, Double, Decimal, DateTime, DateTimeOffset, Time, String, Binary.

Comment: This explains why the OP's code doesn't work, but doesn't really answer the question of how to get the latest record if Guids are used.

Comment: Sure, but I think the OP wasn't aware of this as he didn't ask for a solution but just wondered about the error.

Comment: I understand where you're coming from, but the title is literally "How can get the latest inserted record via Linq to Entities?".  I just think your answer would be better if you included code for getting the last record inserted.